# Exclusion of particular vertices in FeynArts

Tags: feyncalc

I am trying to generate diagrams for H -> ZZ process at one loop level. I only want these 5 diagrams in the final output given by (T1 P1 N1), (T1 P2 N2), (T8 P1 N12), (T9 P1 N14), (T10 P1 N16) given in the following FeynArts diagrams output. Can Anyone please tell me that how can I remove rest of the diagrams. Is their any particular command that I can use to remove particular vertices or couplings in FeynArts. If yes, please explain it with an example.

THANKS,
[image]

Comment: You can write your own filters using `DiagramSelect` (cf. page 30 in the FA manual), but I'm not an expert on this, so I can't really provide examples. If you know which diagrams you need, it's usually easier to extract them explicitly as in `CreateFeynAmp[DiagramExtract[diags,{5,6,7,8}]`. Regarding the wavefunction corrections, you can remove them already during the topology generation stage using the `ExcludeTopologies` option (cf. page 13 in the manual).